# How can I use fields from a previous join in the where criteria of my derived table?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

Example:

```
SELECT fbs_household_id,fbh_file_no, fbc_last_name,fbc_first_name
    FROM fbs_household
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT fbc_household_id, fbc_last_name,fbc_first_name FROM fbs_client WHERE fbc_household_id=fbs_household_id ORDER BY fbc_dob ASC LIMIT 1) t1 ON 1;
```

`fbs_household_id` is from the `fbs_household` table, but I get an error saying unknown field.

I can rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT fbs_household_id,fbh_file_no, fbc_last_name,fbc_first_name
    FROM fbs_household
        LEFT JOIN fbs_client ON fbs_client_id=(SELECT fbs_client_id
            FROM fbs_client
            WHERE fbc_household_id=fbs_household_id ORDER BY fbc_dob ASC LIMIT 1)
```

But this is very slow. Is there any way I can speed it up?

I'm trying to get the oldest member of each household, along with some other information about that household (actual query contains a few more columns and joins).

---

A 3rd solution, also slow:

```
SELECT fbs_household_id,fbh_file_no, fbc_last_name,fbc_first_name
    FROM fbs_household
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT fbc_household_id, fbc_last_name,fbc_first_name
        FROM fbs_client
        ORDER BY fbc_dob ASC) c1 ON fbc_household_id=fbs_household_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one that finds the oldest client in each house hold by doing a self join of each row in the client table to the rows for older members of the same household, and then selecting the one for which no such older person is found.

```
SELECT fbs_household_id, fbh_file_no, c1.fbc_last_name, c1.fbc_first_name
FROM fbs_household
LEFT JOIN fbs_client c1 
ON c1.fbc_household_id = fbs_household_id 
LEFT JOIN fbs_client c2
ON c1.household_id = c2.household_id
AND (c1.dob > c2.dob
     OR c1.dob = c2.dob 
     AND c1.fbs_client_id > c2.fbs_client_id) -- if same dob, choose lower id
WHERE c2.dob IS NULL
```

Comment: This seems to work and is much faster! Thank you. Just need to do a bit more experimentation before I accept :)

Comment: It confused me for quite awhile because I forgot that a greater DOB means a younger person! I understand how that works now. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but have you tried a subquery to get the `max(fbc_dob)` for each household and then join on the table again to get the other values:

```
SELECT h.fbs_household_id, h.fbh_file_no, c1.fbc_last_name, c1.fbc_first_name
FROM fbs_household h
LEFT JOIN fbs_client c1
  ON h.fbs_household_id = c1.fbc_household_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    select max(fbc_dob) fbc_dob, fbc_household_id  --- this will get you the oldest per household
    from fbs_client
    group by fbc_household_id
) c2
    ON c1.fbc_household_id = c2.fbc_household_id
    AND c1.fbc_dob = c2.fbc_dob
```

**not sure if I placed the aliases on the correct fields in the select.*

Comment: This assumes each household contains at least 1 member, and that the oldest person is unique (unique DOB); neither assumption I can make. If two members have the same age, it can pick one at random. I'll see if I can work with it though...

Comment: yes there are some assumptions that is why I said I am not sure if it will work.  But maybe it can be a starting point for another solution.  This would be much easier if MySQL had windowing functions.